# Jeditable, clean data before sending it to server

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I am trying to use Jeditable, an editor in line plugin for jQuery.

However, I am failing to see how would I process the edited data before sending to the server.

Right now I have this:

```
$('.edit_area').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
         type      : 'textarea',
         cancel    : 'Cancel',
         submit    : 'OK',
         indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
         tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
     });
```

But, how would I process the data before is sent to the server?? I want to clean some characters and I fail to see how to do it.

Comment: Please, **do it serverside**. You have no guarantee the user will be using your form rather than sending a (potentially malicious) request manually.

Comment: Damon, I know. But I want to do it in both places...